# Mac docker no space left on device when building images?

Tags: docker

I've seen this issue a number of times and usually use docker system prune to solve it temporarily, but i'm not understanding why it says there is no space on the device?

The main drive on my mac currently has 170gb free space, i also have a second drive with 900gb free, the images i'm building take up a total of 900mb when built, so what is docker talking about? I have plenty of storage space!

Comment: You are probably running docker on a platform which runs docker inside a linux VM, such as windows or mac. Check the VM config and see how much disk space is allocated for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you specified that the platform is Mac, your docker runtime is running inside a VM, which has it's own resources allocated.

Assuming you are using [Docker For Mac](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/),  you should increase the allocated disk space for the docker VM:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to increase the amount of docker engine storage as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72614386/13541620), you can free some space by running:

```
docker image prune
```